# Custom notification for AUTH_ERROR, status 403

Tags: admin-on-rest

In authClient.js

```
if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
    const { status } = params;
    if (status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return Promise.reject();
    }
    if (status === 403) {
        // Show custom notification here on the Snackbar
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Any tips on how to do show a custom notification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It takes a redux action `showNotification` to trigger the notification, so a custom saga is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use follow link as a stage to resolve your problem https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/180 
Good luck!